# Can we say “front of spring” or merely “beginning of spring”?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, writing

In an [answer](https://writers.stackexchange.com/a/7456/2619) to a Writers SE [question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/7452/best-way-to-emphasise-the-greenness-of-the-fields-in-spring-in-comparison-with-s), I used the phrase “a bright morning at the front of spring”.  John M. Landsberg commented:

> Nice revision, but note we wouldn't say "the front" of a season. In poetry, you *might* make it work, but never in prose. Seasons have temporal length, not physical substance, and they also come and go, so you can say the beginning of spring, the onset of spring, the arrival of spring, and more, but never the front.

Is it true one can never say “the front” of a season in prose?  And is there historical precedent (in the way of grammar dicta) for not applying *[front](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/front#Noun)* to ethereal or ephemeral things?

Comment: Don't say "never".  But certainly that would be used very rarely, and draw attention to itself.

Answer (score 3):

To paraphrase GEdgar, "never say never". But *front* for *beginning [of a time-frame]* is rare today.

As barbie says, *in/the front of X* is normally only used of tangible objects. Unsurprisingly, since etymologically speaking it derives from Latin [frontem (nominative frons)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=front) *forehead, brow, front; facade, forepart; appearance.*

Having said all that, OP can relax, safe in the knowledge that he's in good company. One of dozens of definitions in OED is:

> **7 b.** *transf.* With reference to time: The first period; the beginning. *poet.*
>    1883   R. L. Stevenson "Silverado Squatters" 237  - [like a hawthorn **in the front** of June.](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=S_Jtcew8PucC&pg=PA279&dq=%22in%20the%20front%20of%20june%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1O1EUaDbN7CM0wXDjoGgDg&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22in%20the%20front%20of%20june%22&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a bit odd because *in front of* is basically used before tangible objects. Here the season is intangible. Not always, but maybe in rare cases to talk informally we can use it in front of seasons.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can never say the “front” of a season, because it is a temporal expanse, not a physical one.  You must say the *start* or *beginning* of the season, just as you would of a month, a day, or an hour.